# Check if activation_code is not activeted at login. "ONLY" activation_code

Tags: php, mysql, select

This is the code I use at login:

```
            $q = $lacz->query("SELECT email, pass, activation_code
                                    FROM users
                                    WHERE  email='". $nazwa_uz_l ."' 
                                    AND pass = '". $haslo_l ."' 
                                    AND activation_code IS NULL ");     

        if($q->num_rows>0) {
            $_SESSION['prawid_uzyt'] = $nazwa_uz_l; }
        else 
        {
            echo 'Pass or Log are wrong, or activation code is not confirmed (check email).';
            exit;
        }
```

In this query I check for all 3 things: email, password and activation code, and then output an error. What I want to do is to output an first error when Pass or Log are wrong and second error (something like elseif) when activation code IS not NULL. I tried else if and two queries, but I was getting the errors. Can You help me? I check the answers and give points, thanks.

Comment: Get the row with the corresponding e-mail address and check the rest in php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove "AND activation_code IS NULL" from your query and do something like

```
if($q->num_rows>0) 
{
  $row = $q->fetch_assoc();
  if(!is_null($row['activation_code']))
  {
    $_SESSION['prawid_uzyt'] = $nazwa_uz_l;
  }
  else 
  {
    echo 'Activation code is not confirmed (check email).';
    exit;
  }
}
else 
{
  echo 'Pass or Log are wrong.';
  exit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't check the activation code in the query. Just get the user information, along with the activation code field:

```
SELECT email, pass, activation_code
..
WHERE email='foo' and pass='bar'
```

Then you can test the individual conditions in your code:

```
if (number_of_rows == 0) {
   ... bad username/password
} else if ($activation_code == '') {
   ... code is blank/null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the `AND activation_code IS NULL` from the query's `WHERE` clause, you'll be able to pull data for a user matching the given email/password. Then, with that, you'll be able to determine if the user exists, or if their activation code is empty:

```
$q = $lacz->query("SELECT email, pass, activation_code
        FROM users
        WHERE  email='". $nazwa_uz_l ."' 
        AND pass = '". $haslo_l ."'");

if ($q->num_rows === 0) {
    echo 'Password or email address are wrong.';
    exit;
} else {
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    if (empty($row['activation_code'])) {
        echo 'Activation code is not confirmed.';
        exit;
    } else {
        $_SESSION['prawid_uzyt'] = $nazwa_uz_l;
    }
}
```

Side-note (not answer related): I highly suggest using a parameterized query instead of directly inserting the values into the SQL; if you prefer the current way, make sure you're sanitizing the input first to prevent SQL Injection.